# The state field path 'e.id' cannot be resolved to a valid type. Dynamic entity in orm.xml,

Tags: jpa, orm, eclipselink, jpql, single-table-inheritance

This simple SINGLE_TABLE inheritance hierarchy somehow fails when my application tries to access the inheriting entity RootFolderNode.

The entities are defined as dynamic entities access="VIRTUAL", without a Java class backing. The PersistenceUnit is loaded without any complaints.

```
Exception Description: Problem compiling 
    [SELECT DISTINCT e FROM RootFolderNode e WHERE  e.id =  :param1 ]. 
[46, 50] The state field path 'e.id' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
```

The relevant part of the ORM.xml

```
<entity class="FolderNode" access="VIRTUAL" >
    <table name="FOLDER_NODE_PREPARE" />
    <inheritance strategy="SINGLE_TABLE"/>
    <discriminator-value>F</discriminator-value>
    <attributes>
        <id name="id" attribute-type="Long">
            <column name="id" />
            <generated-value strategy="SEQUENCE" generator="FOLDER_NODE_SEQ" />
            <sequence-generator sequence-name="FOLDER_NODE_SEQ" name="FOLDER_NODE_SEQ" allocation-size="1" />
        </id>
        ...
    </attributes>
</entity>

<entity class="RootFolderNode" parent-class="FolderNode" access="VIRTUAL">
    <discriminator-value>R</discriminator-value>
</entity>
```

What am I missing here?

Products in use: EclipseLink 2.5.1. JBoss EAP 6.2.

Comment: Yes, java.lang.Long. Using just Long works with other entities. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a junit-test?

Comment: Are you using multitenancy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Repeat inheritance specification:

```
<entity class="RootFolderNode" parent-class="FolderNode" access="VIRTUAL">
    <inheritance strategy="SINGLE_TABLE"/>
    <discriminator-value>R</discriminator-value>
</entity>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use inheritance strategy to overcome this.please add the following line in your RootFolderNode.

```
 <inheritance strategy="SINGLE_TABLE"/>
```